# Why isn't first-child working in this CSS documnet

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm wondering why the following CSS fiddle is not just turning off the up arrow on the first child and not any other DIVs.

```
<div id="activeitemslist" class="">
  <div class="ind_item">
      <div class="ind_updn">
          <span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ind_item">
      <div class="ind_updn">
          <span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#activeitemslist{width:100%;border:1px solid red}

#activeitemslist DIV:first-child SPAN.fa-arrow-up {display:none !important }

.ind_item > DIV{display: inline-block;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vvc0a4gx/

Comment: Your code seems to work fine...I think you should have a question...

Comment: Because `#activeitems DIV:first-child` matches divs on all levels inside #activeitems. Change DIV to `.ind_item` or use `#activeitems > DIV:first-child`

Answer (score 1):

#### Hi.

## Where is the problem?

Let's try explain essential part of your CSS rule: `#activeitemslist DIV:first-child`.
It looks for a div which is first child of his parent and parent must be inside element with id="activeitemslist".

According to this both up arrows fit in your rule `#activeitemslist DIV:first-child SPAN.fa-arrow-up {display:none !important }` so both are not displayed.

## Solution

To refer just to first child div of element with id="activeitemslist" CSS rule should looks like `#activeitemslist > div:first-child`.

So to not display first up arrow in exemplary fiddle use follow CSS rule (there is no need to use `!important`):

```
#activeitemslist > div:first-child span.fa-arrow-up {
    display: none;
}
```

[Updated code fiddle from the question with the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/vvc0a4gx/5/).

## Sources

You can read more about CSS3 selectors on e.g. [W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

#### Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I changed the CSS here

```
                #activeitemslist .ind_item:first-child SPAN.fa-arrow-up {display:none !important }
```